# send google hangout notification using python

Tags: python, notifications, google-plus, google-hangouts

Is there an API which allows me to send a notification to Google Hangout? Or is there even a python module which encapsulates the Hangout API?

I would like to send system notification (e.g. hard disk failure reports) to a certain hangout account. Any ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hangouts does not currently have a public API.

That said, messages delivered to the Google Talk XMPP server (talk.google.com:5222) are still being delivered to users via Hangouts. This support is only extended to one-on-one conversations, so the notification can't be delivered to a group of users. The messages will need to be supplied through an authenticated Google account in order to be delivered.

Comment: They killed the Hangouts API: "New apps cannot be created but existing apps will continue to run until April 25th, 2017. After that date, apps in Hangouts will no longer function."

Answer (score 2):

There is pre-alpha library for sending hangouts messages on python:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hangups/0.1

The API have been reverse engineered and is not published (as someone posted in comments). Thus it might change a Google's will.

Also, messages sent using XMPP ceased to be delivered to Hangouts users. I guess this is another cut (of the thousand scheduled).

Answer (score 1):

I send alarms and other notifications with a python script (failures on database server, partitions without free space, etc), using hangouts. It's easy. Look at http://www.administracion-linux.com/2014/07/enviar-mensajes-por-hangout-desde.html to send hangouts.

Comment: A little more explanation with code snippets might help out fellow programmers here to understand

Comment: It simply uses XMPP (alias Jabber) to send the messages. For now it works, but until Google decides to drop the XMPP support.

Comment: i had to translate via google , but the snippet works. thank you :)